# Nashorn Javascript: NativeTypeError

Tags: javascript, jvm, nashorn

The Nashorn Javascript engine (part of Java 8) reports some exceptions, esp. regarding method binding errors like arity or type mismatches, as a `NativeTypeError`-instance, which does not have a `cause` relation to get any exception and is therefore very opaque to me (I'd like to report as much as possible back to the script user).

Is there a documented method to get root causes or further information from a `NativeTypeError`-instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: the semantics of `NativeTypeError` are described in the ECMAScript standard ([ECMA-262, sec. 15.11.7](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.7)). Instances of `NativeTypeError` expose a public field `message`, which is of type `Object`, but is most likely a `String` for all circumstances I've encountered it.

Answer (score 1):

ECMAScript standard only defines name and message properties on Error objects like TypeError, ReferenceError etc.

Nashorn defines certain extension properties such as "lineNumber", "columnNumber", "fileName" (for the source where exception was thrown from) and "stack" to access stack trace. Also "printStackTrace", "getStackTrace" functions are supported via Error.prototype extensions.

See also:

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-ExtensionsofErrorobjects,Error.prototypeandErrorconstructor